# Convert functional Java 8 stream function to Java 7

Tags: java, java-8, java-7

My project uses Java 7 and can not be upgraded to Java 8, but according to time I will need a class to authenticate a method. That class contains a method that uses Java 8 Stream API to join a Map into a String by using Collectors.joining(), which is all functionality of Java 8.
I have searched a lot in order to transform it into valid Java 7 code but did not manage it and need help with it.

```
private static String getSignatureBaseString(String url, String method, Map<String, String> parameters) {
    String requestURL = urlEncode(url);
    // 1. Percent encode every key and value that will be signed.
    Map<String, String> encodedParameters = percentEncodeParameters(parameters);

    // 2. Sort the list of parameters alphabetically by encoded key.
    encodedParameters = getSortedParameters(encodedParameters);

    String paramsString = **mapToString(encodedParameters, SpecialSymbol.EQUAL.getEncoded(), SpecialSymbol.AMP.getEncoded());

    return String.format(BASE_SIGNATURE_FORMAT, method, requestURL, paramsString);
}

//========
private static String mapToString(Map<String, String> paramsMap, String keyValueDelimiter, String paramsDelimiter) {
    //**this return
    return paramsMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + keyValueDelimiter + entry.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.joining(paramsDelimiter));
}
```

Comment: Iterate over Map with ```for``` loop and collect data to ```StringBuilder```.

Comment: Okay, but how do I replace the entry?

Comment: ```Map.Entry``` is interface from ```java.util```. You shouldn't replace it. Just change the way you iterate over ```Map```

Comment: ok, if you can leave some code as an example, it would be of help.

Comment: correctly code, thnx

Answer (score 0):

Just run over the entries and add the key/value pair into a StringBuilder. Collectors.joining() prevents that `paramsDelimiter` is inserted at the end. This is catched in the for-loop by the check of the `firstLoop` variable.

```
private static String mapToString(Map<String, String> paramsMap, String keyValueDelimiter, String paramsDelimiter)
{
    boolean firstLoop = true;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : paramsMap.entrySet())
    {
        if (!firstLoop)
        {
            builder.append(paramsDelimiter);
        }
        builder.append(entry.getKey());
        builder.append(keyValueDelimiter);
        builder.append(entry.getValue());

        firstLoop = false;
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```